# Filtering the collection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a collection of models with boolean value `interviewed` and I want to filter them so that my view would display either models with this property set to `true` or models with this property set to `false`. In my collection I have the following methods:

```
var ResumeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    filterActive: function () {
        var active = this.where({interviewed: false});
        return active;
    },

    filterInterviewed: function () {
        var interviewed = this.where({interviewed: true});
        return interviewed;
    }
});
```

and in my view I have the following:

```
var ResumeList = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #active': 'showActive',
        'click #interviewed': 'showInterviewed'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new ResumeCollection();
    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.html( $('#filter') );
        _.each(this.collection.toArray(), function (cv) {
            self.$el.append((new ResumeView({model: cv})).render().$el);
        });
    },

    showActive: function () {
        this.collection.filterActive();
        this.render();
    },

    showInterviewed: function () {
        this.collection.filterInterviewed();
        this.render();
    }
});
```

But any time I click `#active` or `#interviewed` buttons, it happens nothing and the models with required properties aren't rendered. I've already tried to manage that with `reset` method or returning a new collection instance with required models, but that's not a solution, because when I succesfully filter the initial collection, it returns me a new collection with the models I need (e.g. models where `interviewed: true`), and I can't filter it more -- it returns just an empty collection.
I just can't get how can I filter this one collection in the way I need.

Comment: You have to filter the the models inside collections, and return the filtered models. In your case `interviewed` is only a collection parameter.

Comment: I've got `interviewed` parameter as default in my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a successfully filtered collection, and then not doing anything with them.

```
showActive: function () {
    this.collection.filterActive();//returns a value you're not using
    this.render();
},

showInterviewed: function () {
    this.collection.filterInterviewed();//returns a value you're not using
    this.render();
}
```

I suggest adding an optional parameter to your render method that represents the filtered collection. If the parameter is defined, use it. If not, use the unfiltered collection.

Borrowing some of @Simo's code to return a new collection.

```
filterActive: function () {
    var active = this.where({interviewed: false});
    return new ResumeCollection(active);
},

filterInterviewed: function () {
    var interviewed = this.where({interviewed: true});
    return new ResumeCollection(interviewed);
},

render: function (filtered) {
    var self = this;
    var data = filtered ? filtered.toArray() : this.collection.toArray();
    this.$el.html( $('#filter') );
    _.each(data , function (cv) {
        self.$el.append((new ResumeView({model: cv})).render().$el);
    });
},

showActive: function () {
    var filtered = this.collection.filterActive();
    this.render(filtered);
},

showInterviewed: function () {
    var filtered = this.collection.filterInterviewed();
    this.render(filtered);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works almost perfectly and does what I need except one error -- when the view is rendered for the first time, it returns me an error `filtered.toArray is not a function` and renders nothing. But when I click on buttons, the events act exactly as I need and render the models I need. Any suggestions about that bug?

Comment: **ADDED** I'm looking in the debugger now and it seems that when the view is rendered for the first time, `data` receives an empty array first, and then becomes `undefined`, which causes the error

Comment: When the view renders for the first time, are you passing in any arguments? If not, then the ternary operator should default to `this.collection.toArray()`. If you do pass in an argument, the render function expects it to be a Backbone collection.

Comment: I've got the following line in my `router.js` : `this.layout.render(new ResumeList({collection: new ResumeCollection() });`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not returning the filtered collection.

This should work:

```
filterActive: function () {
    var active = this.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('interviewed') === false;
    });

    return new ResumeCollection(active);
},

filterInterviewed: function () {
    var interviewed = this.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('interviewed') === true;
    });

    return new ResumeCollection(interviewed);
},
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work :( and here I get as a result a new collection -- but what if I need to filter for those with different parameter now? I mean, if these functions succeed, in the result I get a collection of models where `interview === false`. But then I won't be able to filter for the collections where `interview === true`, unless I refresh the page manually

Comment: I don't get it: why do you need to refresh the browser manually to get the collection where `interview == true`?

Comment: because whenever I filter an initial collection, I get a new collection with models that have only either `interviewed === true` or `interviewed === false` parameters, which makes impossible to filter it again. I mean, for example, I successfully filter the initial collection, and get a new collection of models with `interviewed === false`. Then, if I want to filter the collection again and if I filter it, I just get an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to modify you render function to accept a argument which will be array of models.

Now when rendering full collection you can call render as

```
render(this.collection.models) // reference to list of models
```

also if you filter out the collection then the filter function most probably be returning the subset of models from collection. Which you can again pass to render function

```
this.render(this.showActive()) // showActive returns subset of models from collection
```

This way your render function becomes modular.. which accepts array and render then on page..

Now for Filtering out Collection you can use filter , where methods exposed by underscore .. **Remember to capture the return and pass it along to render Function..**